# How to add customize HTML validation error as per condition?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a input that is type text where i want to enter just phone number with 10 digits. I'm using HTML validation as given below its working fine but when i'm adding custom HTML validation error that is not working fine as per situation always display `Please enter numbers only` but I want to add as per situation.

What i tried:-

```html
<form action="">
  <label>Contact Number</label>
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter numbers only')" class="form-control" name="contact_number" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried tel input type?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfunc(){

 var name = document.forms['det']['name']
 var age = document.forms['det']['age']
 var par = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

 if(name.value == ""){
   var text = document.createElement('p');
   name.parentNode.insertBefore(text, name.nextSibling);
   if(par.length == 1){
    text.innerHTML = "Enter your name";
   }
   return false;
 }

 if(age.value == ""){
  var text = document.createElement('p');
  age.parentNode.insertBefore(text, age.nextSibling);
  text.innerHTML = "Enter your age";
  if(par.length == 1){
   text.innerHTML = "Enter your name";
  }
  return false;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<form name="det" id="form" onsubmit="return myfunc();">
 <input type="text" class="editor" name="name" placeholder="name">
 <input type="text" class="editor" name="age" placeholder="age">
 <input type="submit" id="button" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This is how to can print your error message what every you want to print.

Comment: error message print each times when i click no submit button without enter any value in input control

Comment: Please check the above code i have edited the new changes!

Answer (score 0):

MDN has some good documentation in this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity

I've adapted the article to your code below

```js
//Get the element
var el = document.getElementById("inTest");
//Set the method to execute on in valid
el.oninvalid = invalidNum;
//Function to execute
function invalidNum(event) {
  //just to see what is available
  console.log(this.validity);

  //If empty
  if (this.validity.valueMissing) {
    this.setCustomValidity("Please enter a contact number");
    //If pattern missmatch
  } else if (this.validity.patternMismatch) {
    this.setCustomValidity("Please enter exactly 10 didgits");
    //Something else
  } else {
    this.setCustomValidity("Please enter only numbers");
  }

}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <label>Contact Number</label>
  <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" id="inTest" class="form-control" name="contact_number" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The form submits for me with 10 digits in Safari, Firefox and Chrome on Mac OSX. What browser?